# Using GCD for daily executed method?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

if i need a method in my iPhone app that shoud be executed once a day - is GCD the right way to do it? ([GCD](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/GCDWorkQueues/GCDWorkQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH103-SW2)

Will this method be executed even if the users closes the app in the task manager?

Answer (score 0):

There's no right way to do it.  Why don't you try an NSTimer?

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html

The method will not be executed if the user explicitly stops your app from running.